# How to check iOS app is paid when updating new app version with in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

I have my paid app in App Store now I change it to a free app with in-app purchase in new version. (**Auto-Renewable Subscriptions**)

I want to give free for the user's who purchased the previous version.
I have some questions here:

1) How to check app purchased or not in code (Swift) ? I tried use **SKPaymentTransactionObserver** but I can't check history purchases.

2) How to test update from paid app (App downloaded from Store) to new version app (With Auto-Renewable Subscriptions by Sandbox account) ?

Comment: Check this out [iOS Receipt Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44116593/apple-receipt-original-purchase-date-has-date-before-app-creation/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Apple will not issue any commands to the `SKPaymentObserver` unless you are making an in-app purchase. It has nothing to do with the original purchase of the app.
2. You can determine the original purchase date of the application by validating the iTunes Receipt with Apple and reading the `original_application_version` field. This would tell you if the user bought your app while it was a paid application. Apple has a guide for reading the AppStore receipt [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)